# Angular Directive Method Binding ng-select

Tags: angularjs

When I change a select it fires all the method bindings for other selects that are using the same directive. Is this the expected behavior? For instance if I change the state select, it will fire stateselected and also dogselected..Am I missing a fundamental understanding of Angular Directives? I notice if I do this without a directive, this is not the behavior.

Here is my plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/inKtjY?p=preview

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

    app.controller('controller', function ($scope) {

        $scope.firstName = "Michael";

        $scope.states = [{ id: 1, name: 'Nebraska' }, { id: 2, name: 'Iowa' }];
        $scope.state = $scope.states[0];
        $scope.stateselected = function (state) {

            console.log('state selected:', state);
        };


        $scope.dogs = [{ id: 11, name: 'Poodle' }, { id: 12, name: 'Pitbull' }];
        $scope.dog = $scope.dogs[0];
        $scope.dogselected = function (dog) {

            console.log('dog selected:', dog);
        };
    });

    app.directive('myselect', function () {

        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            template: '<select ng-model="item" ng-options="i as i.name for i in itemlist " ng-selected="itemselected()"></select>',
            scope: {
                item: '=',
                itemlist: '=',
                itemselected: '&'
            }
        };
    });
```

html

```
<div ng-controller="controller">

    State:<myselect item='state' itemlist='states' itemselected='stateselected(state)'></myselect><br>

    Dogs: <myselect item='dog' itemlist='dogs' itemselected='dogselected(dog)'></myselect><br>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are looking for the `ngChange` directive not `ngSelected`. Try modifying your directive template to this:

```
<select ng-model="item" ng-options="i as i.name for i in itemlist" ng-change="itemselected()"></select>
```

Now you will notice that your functions get called when the value of your `ngModel` is changed. If you were to use the `ngRepeat` directive on the `<option>` element (instead of using `ngOptions`) you would be able to put an expression in `ngSelected` on the `<option>` element, which would be used to determine which option is currently selected.

The reason why this is happening with `ngSelected`, is because that directive is expecting an expression to evaluate. You passed it a function (which is perfectly fine), so whenever you would update the selection in either `<select>`, it would force an Angular digest loop (because your `ngModel` was being changed). It would eventually reach your `ng-selected="itemselected()"` expression and try to evaluate it by executing it.

Comment: I did try to use ng-changed and I noticed it was firing the events before the item was actually changed. I thank you for you response, because it allows me look into and learn about this digest. I think there is a better way to do this with $watch, but I though this simple solution would work..